# Joi use default when value is invalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I am trying to validate some data using Joi. However, I want to use the default value when the provided value is invalid. My current validation looks like this:

```
field: Joi.string()
    .optional()
    .valid('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
    .default('a', { invalid: true }),
```

So when I get for example **y**, validation error is occured and default value is not used. Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  [`alternatives.try(schemas)`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#alternativestryschemas)to achieve what you want by using this schema:

```
  const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    field:  Joi.alternatives().try([
      Joi.string().valid('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
      Joi.empty(Joi.any())
    ]).default('a')
  })
```

You will also be able to achieve this through the [`any.failover(value)`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyfailover) available on joi **16.0.0** (it's not released yet).

Answer (score 2):

Alternate to @soltex answer:

`default` only works if the value is unset. So you can unset the value by using `empty`.(basically this is what I use, don't know about the negative points):

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    field: Joi.string().empty(Joi.not(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])).default('a')
})
```